# How to send text within a textarea using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

**SOLVED**

**Solution:**
I just used firefox instead of chrome, and the problem magically disappeared!

I have a selenium bot that adds products on a website with given information. This use to work but it doesn't now. I want to paste the description in the **textarea** but it goes and pastes the description inside the field **SEO Title**. And chrome browser freezes for some seconds when it comes to pasting the description, this also is new.

It also leaves a little bit of text when clearing, or pasting text in the upper area, I have no idea why.

Code is here.

```
textarea = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea#content")
textarea.clear()
textarea.click()
textarea.send_keys(str(desc))
```

This clears the wanted textarea, but sends the keys to the wrong place, need help.

*This is the place where it should paste the description*

[image: This is the place where it should paste the description]

*This is the place called SEO Title, and it pastes the description here instead of the textarea*

[image: This is the place called SEO Title, and it pastes the description here instead of the textarea]

*Example image showing the error, text should be in the upper text area*

[image: Example of error]

*untouched image of the two areas mentioned*

[image: Image of the area involved in this question]

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* with in the `<textarea>` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  textarea = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea.wp-editor-area#content[name='content']")
  textarea.click()
  textarea.clear()
  textarea.send_keys(str(desc))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  textarea = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@class='wp-editor-area' and @id='content'][@name='content']")
  textarea.click()
  textarea.clear()
  textarea.send_keys(str(desc))
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  textarea = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.wp-editor-area#content[name='content']")))
  textarea.click()
  textarea.clear()
  textarea.send_keys(str(desc))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  textarea = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@class='wp-editor-area' and @id='content'][@name='content']")))
  textarea.click()
  textarea.clear()
  textarea.send_keys(str(desc))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this also didn't change anything except that it didn't paste a little bit of text on the wanted textarea.